# Classification of unitary pointed monoidal category

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

I wonder if the following classification results are true (and are there any references):

1. Unitary pointed monoidal categories (the fusion rule of the objects is given by a finite group $G$) are classified by a pair $(G,\omega_3)$
   up to a group automorphism. Here $\omega_3 \in H^3(G; U(1))$ is a group 3-cohomology class.
2. Unitary pointed monoidal 2-categories (the fusion rule of the objects is given by a finite group $G$) are classified by a pair $(G,\omega_4)$
   up to a group automorphism. Here $\omega_4 \in H^4(G; U(1))$ is a group 4-cohomology class.

Comment: I think result 1 is "well known", and probably in standard references on fusion categories. 2 is a bit more subtle, because the phrase "monoidal 2-category" carries a lot of content, and so you should be dubious of too-quick "proofs". I think I know a way to formulate 2 so that it is true.

Comment: I should mention one of the things you have to handle when trying to prove 2. When proving 1, you get lucky in that over $\mathbb C$, all simple objects in a semisimple category have endomorphism algebra $\mathbb C$. If you wanted to prove a version over some other field, you would need to think harder, and use that other division rings are not $\otimes$-invertible (in algebras and homomorphisms --- they are invertible in algebras and bimodules). In a 2-categorical setting, algebras get categorified to fusion categories, and division rings become fusion categories with no algebra objects...

Comment: ... I think. (I should think through more carefully what the categorification of "division ring" is.) Anyway, it remains true, and I guess it isn't too hard, to know that nontrivial fusion categories are not $\boxtimes$-invertible. The reason you need this type of statement is so that every object in your monoidal 2-category, since it is invertible, has only $\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb C}$ as its endo-category, and not some worse fusion category.

Comment: About 1. The classification of pointed fusion categories can be found in the monograph "Tensor Categories", I guess but I don't know the original reference. That all of them are unitary follows, in principle, from Vaughan Jones PhD thesis. Namely, what's called a G-kernel in Operator algebras gives a pointed unitary fusion category. It's unitary by construction. Jones showed that all finite groups and cocycles arise from G-kernels on the hyperfinite $II_1$ factor. I guess unitarity can also be checked directly. About 2. I am curious, too.